# VM Instance group to configure to listen on port 80 and 8080

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gce-instance-group

I have configure my VM in such a way that I have 2 application running on one VM.
 First App listen on ip:80 port
 Second App listen on ip:8080 port

I have enabled ports on VM instances group like this.

[image]

I have my Load Balancer configured with two front rules like this.

[image]

I want to map ip1:80 to my 80 port application and ip2:8080 to 8080 application

when I tried accessing my application using load balancers IP address it always show me 8080 port application.

I have two backend service running 
help me here google team. I m newb

Comment: but what is the endgame here? are you using the load balancer to autoscale? or you just want two diffrent ip addresses?

Comment: of course I want to use this for autoscale. I thought 2 different IP address for 2 ports. Am I doing something terribly wrong??. my 2 applications are nodejs and socket.io. I have a startscript which runs these 2 on port 8080 and 80 automatically on autoscale.

Comment: my auto scaling works, specified number of VM scales on load

Comment: As far as I know url mapping woks with hostnames not ips. You can also  create another group with the same image template but on the second group map the port name "http" to port 8080. there is no such thing as port name "http80" as far as I know.

Comment: and then I have to pay for 2 VMs, isn't it?

Comment: let say If i buy a domain?? will it work??

Comment: you are correct you will need the minimum of 2 vm. if you buy a domain you can use the solution I gave in the other question.

Comment: for testing purposes you can just edit you local hosts file to see if it works. it will also mean you will no be using XX.XX.X.X:8080 to reach your website but a sub.domain.com

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use IP addresses but not URLs/Domain(s) to reach to your web applications, then `URL Maps` cannot help to implement your design, as URL map forwards the request to the correct backend service using `host values (example.com)` and `path values (/path)` in the destination URL.

That being said, you can add one more `Target Proxy` to your LB resources to route incoming requests directly to the desired backend services. This will allow you to keep your minimum number of instances as one VM.

For more information, visit [this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I had to add second backend.
So I have two backends: [one](https://github.com/ypapax/gcloud_load_balancer_two_ports/blob/master/gcloud.sh#L86) for 80 port, [other](https://github.com/ypapax/gcloud_load_balancer_two_ports/blob/master/gcloud.sh#L91) for 8080. And I have on managed group.